# How to validate Date of Birth using Regex in Flutter?

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

I'm trying to take the input of Date of Birth for which I need a formatter which will help me check the date that has been input by the user.

The format is dd-mm-yyyy for which **dd** must be between 1-31; **mm** must be in between 1-12; and **yyyy** must be between 1920-2002 (user must be above 18 to use the app).

I've tried the following code and a lot of other dependencies as well but nothing has helped. Is there a better way to validate a date of birth using Regex?

Dependency used: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_multi_formatter

Code:

```
TextFormField(
validator: (String value) {
if (value.isEmpty) {
return 'Please enter your birthday';
} else if (value.length != 10) {
return 'Please enter a valid birthday';
}
return null;
},
inputFormatters: [
MaskedInputFormatter('00-00-0000',
anyCharMatcher: RegExp(
r'^(0[1-9]|1[012])[-/.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[-/.](19|20)\\d\\d$'))
],
);
```

Comment: FYI you should not double backslashes in a raw string literal. `r'\\d'` matches ``\d``. `r'\d'` matches any digit.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and your question gave me the idea of ​​how to solve it.  So here he sent you an idea of ​​what you can do!

static const dateRegExp =
r'^(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[01])-/.-/.$';

The support formats are 01/01/1990 or 01.01.1990 or 01-01-1990.

Work perfectly with rective_forms package (i recommended)

The only problem is that the user can do some like 01.01/1990 or 01-01.1990.

Pd: i note that stack overflow add -/.-/. between ) and $. Remove it